# Issue when I deploy my wordpress website on GAE

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, deployment

I followed all the steps to deploy my wordpress website on GAE (Running WordPress in App Engine)

When I am entering my address:wp-dot-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com

I am automatically redirected to: wp-dot-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/admin/configure.jsp

Which is definitely not my website. And if I change the path, I have an error 404.

Have you already faced this issue?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you refer to you site as wp-dot-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com when it should actually be YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com.

On first uploading, navigating to YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com should redirect to YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/wp-admin/install.php of this doesn't happen automatically try navigating to the install.php page.